# why javascript not working when i load html form host?

Tags: jquery

This is my code:

```
$(this).on('dblclick',function() {

   var t = $(this)

   $.post('api/get_html',function(html){
      t.html(html);
      /* html like :
       <select>
        <option value="123">123</opion>
         ....
       </select>
      */
   });

   t.find('select').focus();
   $(this).find('select').on('focusout',function(){
      var new_name = $(this).val();
      // here i got undefined
   });

});
```

if do not use the $.post method,just t.html('html'), the focus and focusout worked fine.
so , what i can do to  make this is right?

Comment: check your browser console to see if there are any errors

Comment: What is `type`? Assuming it's a variable holding a valid selector, you either need to use event delegation, or put the event handler inside the callback function so its bound *after* the HTML is put in to the DOM.

Comment: @ Arun P Johny  no error

Comment: @Rory McCrossan  put the event handler inside the callback function still not work

Comment: Are you sure the AJAX request is working then? Have you checked the console or network traffic?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan AJAX request working fine,Remote Address:[::1]:80
Request URL:http://localhost/api/get_html
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK

Comment: When you moved the event handler inside the click handler did you change `$(this)` to `t`? This is required as the scope of `this` will be different within the callback code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the click handler to inside the AJAX request callback, so that the event is bound after the request has completed and the `select` element has been created in the DOM.

```
$(this).on('dblclick', function() {
    var t = $(this)

    $.post('api/get_html', function(html) {
        t.html(html);
        t.find('select').focus().on('focusout', function(){
            var new_name = $(this).val();
            console.log(new_name);
        });
    });
});
```